# Experiencing slow browsing in Web application deployed in IIS on local network while data is provided by desktop application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, iis

I'm experiencing slow browsing in the web application. The whole structure of the application is like this:

1. Web Application is built using .Net 5. (alias A)
2. REST API is developed in Spring Boot. (alias B)
3. An Open Source desktop application named JISIS Suite by UNESCO as data source. (alias C)

I've tested the following configurations in deployment.

***Local Network (alias N1) | Offline | With Domain Controller***

***Local Network (alias N2) | Online  | No Domain Controller***

**1. Local Network (N1) = Delay/Slow Browsing**

1. Web App in IIS & Rest API in Tomcat on Web Server (PC-1).
2. Desktop App running in VM on Data Server (PC-2).
3. Client-PC3 to browse Web App.

**2. Local Network (N1) = No Delay/Fast Browsing**

1. Web App in IIS & Rest API in Tomcat on Web Server (PC-1).
2. Desktop App running on Client-PC3.
3. Client-PC3 to browse Web App.

**3. Local Network (N1) = Delay/Slow Browsing**

1. Web App in IIS & Rest API in Tomcat on Web Server (PC-1).
2. Desktop App running on Client-PC3.
3. Client-PC4 to browse Web App.

**4. Local Network (N2) = No Delay/Fast Browsing**

1. Web App in IIS & Rest API in Tomcat on PC1.
2. Desktop App running on PC2.
3. PC3 & PC4 to browse Web App.

The data/response is returned after 30 or 40 seconds. After some testing, I found that there is no delay between A & B (Web App & Rest API). The delay is between B & C (**Rest API & Desktop App**). What are the possible factors of this delay? The final destination to deploy all these is Local Network (N1).

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so please negotiate. If I'm missing some details, feel free to ask.

Comment: How the web app in IIS and rest api send or get data from desktop app? Something you need to figure out first is where the delay happened. Check log of IIS and tomcat to know when application send request to desktop for data, then check log of desktop app to know when it receive the request.

Comment: @BruceZhang The Web App in IIS is receiving data as soon as returned by API. I have confirmed it. The API is using Jisis-core.jar library to make connection to Desktop App. Desktop App has built-in Tomcat server. The Desktop App (Java CDS/ISIS) & jisis-core.jar are open source software by UNESCO. The d-app is using the same .jar internally. Also, there is no problem with jisis-core.jar & desktop app in terms of communication. But due to unknown reason, the delay is only in Case 1 & 3 (stated above in question). It is some kind of network related issue not software problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.